# Linq to SQL vs Entity Data Model: Getting a stored proc to run

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Was I was previously messing with Silverlight and RIA, I was using a an ADO.NET Entity Data Model and domain context. I'm teaching myself how to run a stored procedure from RIA, and could not get it to work with the previous setup so I then started to try out using the [LINQ to SQL](http://www.csharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/958/Default.aspx) method. I did the following:

- Added the DBML
- Drag and dropped my table and example stored proc
- Saved the DBML and built and *rebuilt* the solution and project files.
- Create a Domain Service and attempt to add the dbml.

**Here is my DBML**
[image]

Here is my error. The *Available DataContext/ObjectContext classes* list shows up empty. I have rebuilt many times and even have restarted visual studio. 
[image]

So here are my questions:

1. Is there an easy way to do a stored proc with ADO.Net that I was missing therfore I could skip adding a LINQtoSQL class.
2. Am I missing something really simple to add the dbml class and add a stored proc that way.

**CODE**

ZipCodeDataClasses.dbml.layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ordesignerObjectsDiagram dslVersion="1.0.0.0" absoluteBounds="0, 0, 11, 8.5" name="ZipCodeDataClasses">
  <DataContextMoniker Name="/ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext" />
  <nestedChildShapes>
    <classShape Id="de7acfae-754b-4577-b227-3a33198fdc95" absoluteBounds="7.125, 2.375, 2, 1.3862939453125">
      <DataClassMoniker Name="/ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext/ZipCode" />
      <nestedChildShapes>
        <elementListCompartment Id="8744ad5e-7b77-4770-911d-6dc963876e40" absoluteBounds="7.14, 2.835, 1.9700000000000002, 0.8262939453125" name="DataPropertiesCompartment" titleTextColor="Black" itemTextColor="Black" />
      </nestedChildShapes>
    </classShape>
  </nestedChildShapes>
</ordesignerObjectsDiagram>
```

ZipCodeDataClasses.designer.cs

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace StoredProcedureTest.Web
{
 using System.Data.Linq;
 using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Linq.Expressions;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System;


 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="ZIPCODES")]
 public partial class ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
 {

  private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    #endregion

  public ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext() : 
    base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZIPCODESConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

  public ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext(string connection) : 
    base(connection, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

  public ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
    base(connection, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

  public ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
    base(connection, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

  public ZipCodeDataClassesDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
    base(connection, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

  public System.Data.Linq.Table<ZipCode> ZipCodes
  {
   get
   {
    return this.GetTable<ZipCode>();
   }
  }

  [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.sp_GetCityByZip")]
  public int sp_GetCityByZip([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ZIP", DbType="NVarChar(10)")] string zIP, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Return", DbType="NVarChar(26)")] ref string @return)
  {
   IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), zIP, @return);
   @return = ((string)(result.GetParameterValue(1)));
   return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
  }
 }

 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.ZipCodes")]
 public partial class ZipCode
 {

  private string _City;

  private string _State;

  private int _Zip;

  public ZipCode()
  {
  }

  [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_City", DbType="VarChar(25)")]
  public string City
  {
   get
   {
    return this._City;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._City != value))
    {
     this._City = value;
    }
   }
  }

  [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_State", DbType="VarChar(2)")]
  public string State
  {
   get
   {
    return this._State;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._State != value))
    {
     this._State = value;
    }
   }
  }

  [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Zip", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
  public int Zip
  {
   get
   {
    return this._Zip;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._Zip != value))
    {
     this._Zip = value;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to get Stored Procedures to work with Silerlight, however following this guide was the closest I ever came to an actual implementation. I hope it helps.

http://anhonga.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/using-stored-procedures-with-silverlight-4riapocos-part-ii/

If you ever find a simple way to get stored procedures implemented let me know, because I am in the middle of rewriting a few hundred procedures in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Proved helpful. I found a video which helped me understand what was going on a little better, hopefully it will help you as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd565862.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. The video looks good I will have to try out the implementation and see if I can get it to work.